# Better way to add an element to a serialized list without duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

the following code works, but is there a better way to do this, because I don't like the way and I'm not a pro in JS.

jQuery 1.11.0 is available.

```
value = "newvalue";
serializeList = "oldvalue1;oldvalue2;oldvalue3";

tmp = serializeList.split(';');
if ($.inArray(value, tmp) == -1) {
    tmp.push(value);
}
serializeList = tmp.join(";");
```

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ohh, I didn't knew about this site, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value = 'newvalue';
if (serializeList.indexOf(value + ';') === -1 && serializeList.indexOf(';' + value) === -1) {
    serializeList += ';' + value;
}
```

Comment: The method is not correct as it will fail iif has text like of `serializeList = "newvalue1;";` OP code is better